# Como pegar o valor desse Array em php?

Tags: php, array, post, axios

Estou fazendo um axios.post e enviando um objeto com JSON.stringfy()

No meu arquivo php dei var_dump na resposta e o $POST me retorna um array assim:

array(1) {↵  ["{"placa":"","ano_modelo":"","ano_fabr":"","chassi":"","renavam":"","marca":"",

com o print_r ele vem assim:

[{"placa":"","ano_modelo":"","ano_fabr":"","chassi":"","renavam":"","marca":""

Porém não consigo pegar o valor desse array na minha função, já tentei $body['placa'] e nada.. se alguem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Aparentemente você não está usando json_decode (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) no recebimento do dado via post, no PHP.

Comment: Não é isso, quando eu tento usar o decode ele fala que não é uma string, justamente porque eu tenho um array, como mostrei a cima

Comment: Então, é para usar nos elementos do array.

Comment: Como realmente chega a sua string? Com o print_r?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) para ler a string que está no formato json e depois convertê-la para o objeto json

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

   $value = '[{"placa":"JXK02939","ano_modelo":"","ano_fabr":"","chassi":"","renavam":"","marca":""}]';
   $jsonValue = json_decode( $value );
   $values = $jsonValue[0];
   echo "<blockquote>";
   echo "Placa: ".$values->placa."<br>";
   echo "Ano Modelo: ".$values->ano_modelo."<br>";
   echo "Ano Fabricacao: ".$values->ano_fabr."<br>";
   echo "Chassi: ".$values->chassi."<br>";
   echo "Renavam: ".$values->renavam."<br>";
   echo "Marca: ".$values->marca."<br>";
   echo "</blockquote>";
?>
```

Caso seja apenas um objeto

Caso você queira fazer o loop pode usar o foreach

```
foreach ($jsonValue as $key => $value) {
       echo "<blockquote>";
       echo "Placa: ".$value->placa."<br>";
       echo "Ano Modelo: ".$value->ano_modelo."<br>";
       echo "Ano Fabricacao: ".$value->ano_fabr."<br>";
       echo "Chassi: ".$value->chassi."<br>";
       echo "Renavam: ".$value->renavam."<br>";
       echo "Marca: ".$value->marca."<br>";
       echo "</blockquote>";
   }
```

Espero ter ajudado..

Comment: Então, o que acontece é que como mostrei a cima, eu não tenho uma string por fora do array para usar o decode

Comment: Você tem um array de string com formato json?